# MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, schema, objectid

I am having these schemas:

```
//first
{
  books: Number,
  author: String
}

//second
{
  book_id: ObjectId,
  price: Number,
  name: String
}
```

Now that any document has unique _id I want to take the _id from the first document and assign it to book_id from second document so I can find it later by:

```
db.collection.find({_id: user_id})
```

Do I have to use as a type of book_id : ObjectId and if I have to how should I continue ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me... What is `user_id`? Are your two schemas in the same collection? Each document has a unique `_id` that is immutable. Aren't you trying to do relationships between two *tables* (whether in the same collection or not)? In this case I suggest you visit the [MongoDB reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/).